# How to add success message and failure messages in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I have requirement that:

- After submitting the request, Liferay displays the message

> Your    request processed successfully

- Instead of that I have to add custom messages and display them like course created
  successfully, course deleted successfully, course modified successfully etc..

Is it possible? Is there any way to display the success or failure message?

```
<%@page import ="javax.portlet.PortletURL" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.RenderResponse" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.ActionRequest" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator" %>
<% 

PortletURL searchCourseURL=renderResponse.createActionURL(); 

searchCourseURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,"findCourses"); 

%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<form action="<%=searchCourseURL%>" method="post">
<div class="label1">Enter Course Name</div><input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value=" "/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In the above example, after submitting the request it displays like request process successfully instead I have to display the message:

> search is completed

Comment: For failure messages check this question, it happens to be my answer :): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032229/how-to-show-error-message-in-liferay-portal/11034587#11034587

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Success messages**

In the JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:success key="key" message="message" />
<liferay-ui:success key="key1" message="message1" />
```

In *Language.properties file*

```
message=search is completed...
message1=search is completed...
```

In Controller

```
SessionMessages.add(request, "key");
SessionMessages.add(request, "key1");
```

**Error (failure) messages**

In the JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:error key="error-key" message="error-message" />
<liferay-ui:error key="error-key1" message="error-message1" />
```

In *Language.properties file*:

```
error-message=search couldn't be completed...
error-message1=search couldn't be completed...
```

In Controller:

```
SessionErrors.add(request, "error-key");
SessionErrors.add(request, "error-key1");
```

Comment: if i want to add it for multiple requests with various messages will it work? if it work then how to write?

Comment: where <liferay-ui:success key="key" message="message" /> i have to use  this ? in jsp

Comment: i added but its not showing any message.what i did is:   in jsp below the form     <liferay-ui:success key="key" message="message" />    in the action method i have written SessionMessages.add(request, "key"); next i modified message=search is completed...

Comment: String successMsg = "Course added Successfully!";
SessionMessages.add(request, "request_processed", successMsg); i added like this in my action method. its working! thanks a lot for all u for helping!