# Liferay cleans the session thus cleans the message that i add into SessionErrors.add in an EXT plugin in Liferay 6.1

Tags: extjs, liferay-6

This question can be considered an extension of [How to show error message in liferay portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032229/how-to-show-error-message-in-liferay-portal)

Working on an EXT plugin in liferay 6.1 and customizing UpdateLookAndFeelAction, I am putting an error message into `SessionMessages.add(request,"custom-error-msg");` but seems like the portlet lifecycle cleans the session in `PortalRequestProcessor.java`(Line 186) thus deleting the session message as well. A normal `Your settings were saved successfull is rendered` How can i stop the further execution in my custom `UpdateLookAndFeelAction` and render this error message on `/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp`

I have added the `<liferay-ui:error key="custom-error-msg" message="custom.error.msg" />` in `view.jsp`

I think i read somewhere that you i have to create a hook and customize `end.jsp`. Is that the right approach? Any suggestions and directions will be much appreciated.

Comment: SessionErrors are handled for a portlet level. What you are trying to do is updating UpdateLookAndFeelAction file through ext and reading the error in portlet view.jsp.

So, try 2nd option with <liferay-ui:error exception="<%=AuthException.class%>" message="authentication-failed" /> and in your ext action file catch an exception and set session error SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, se.getClass().getName());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to override `look_and_feel.js` as following:

```
var saveHandler = function(event, id, obj) {
                    var ajaxResponseMsg = instance._portletMsgResponse;
                    var ajaxResponseHTML = '<div id="lfr-portlet-css-response"></div>';
                    var message = '';
                    var messageClass = '';
                    var type = 'success';
                    ***var customErrorMessage = obj.response;***

                    ***if (obj.statusText.toLowerCase() == 'ok' && obj.response != '') {
                        type = 'customError';
                    }***
                    if (obj.statusText.toLowerCase() != 'ok') {
                        type = 'error';
                    }
                    if (type == 'success') {
                        message = Liferay.Language.get('your-request-processed-successfully');
                        messageClass = 'portlet-msg-success';
                    }
                    ***else if(type == 'customError') {
                        message = customErrorMessage;
                        /*message = Liferay.Language.get('custom.error.msg');*/
                        messageClass = 'portlet-msg-error';
                    }***
                    else {
                        message = Liferay.Language.get('your-settings-could-not-be-saved');
                        messageClass = 'portlet-msg-error';
                    }
```

In UpdateLookAndFeel i had to return the custom error message in json object.